# Display sitecore treelist selected in cshtml

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

[Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC47v.png)

Display selected values in cshtml file
wrote this code but it's not working

```
    List<Item> lstWellnessName = null;

     Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField WellnessList = 
      WellnessItem.Fields["Property Wellness"];

        if (WellnessList != null && WellnessList.TargetIDs != null)
        {
            Item[] result = WellnessList.GetItems();
            lstWellnessName = result.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? How are you rendering this in your cshtml, please add code samples.

Comment: This code can work, what is your result? is WellnessItem your home item? else try Sitecore.Context.Item to display the item use something like this if lstWellnessName != null @foreach(var a in lstWellnessName)
{
    <p>@a.Name</p>
}

Comment: the code is working now.After syncing with sitecore its working fine.Thanks for looking into it

Comment: One more doubt  <h1>@Model.PropertyName</h1> is working how to render as @Html.Sitecore().Field("Property Name") .included namespace